# ui automation viewer -adb -error obtaining device screenshot -no android devices were detected by adb

Tags: android, adb, ui-automation

I'm trying to work with uiautomation viewer. When I connect to it and press "device screenshot" button, I get:

> no android devices were detected by adb
>
> error obtaining devices
>   screenshot

Resources:

- Windows 10  (host) running `adb` server `"adb -a nodaemon server"`
- Linux guest (virtual box) -run `adb` devices from it and get the id of the device (so far so good).

On Linux, I installed Android Studio and try via `sdk>tool>bin` to run the `uiautomation` viewer.

What's done so far :(according to answers all over the net)
Change the path inside uiautomationviewer file to :
`Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=/home/ohad/Android/Sdk/tools` (while in /bin we have the uiautomationvewr file.

The path of adb is ("adb which")- `/home/ohad/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`